# Why Value To Variable X Increasing In Function?

Tags: go

I am unable to understand to why value of x increase even after scope end for varaiable ‘x’ in function foo(). It’s must reset to zero everytime I called a function. This this not happening why?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := foo()

    fmt.Printf("%d\n", a())
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", a())
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", a())

}

func foo() func() int {

    var x int //  value should reset to zero
    return func() int {
        x++
        return x
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RSl3uNv6bBo)

Comment: Value of `x` "resets" every time you call _`foo()`_ (or more precisely you get a new instance of `x`), but you only call `foo()` once. Later you call the function value it returns, which is a closure, closing over a single instance of `x`.

Comment: To plainly demonstrate @icza's point: https://play.golang.org/p/C0OkKffYqGf

Answer (score 1):

Your function `foo` returns a new function each time it's called. `foo` doesn't *just* create that function though, it also allocates memory for a variable called `x` of type `int`. That variable is declared in the scope of `foo`, and as such, the function `foo` returns has access to that variable.

In essence, you're returning what is often referred to as a *closure*. A function that has access to a scope (variables) that are invisible to any other code. To visually represent this, maybe thing of it like this:

[image: closure]

The function is what you return, the *"environment record"* it holds on to is the function body of `foo`, and all of the variables declared there (in your case `x`). The next environment record would be the package (variables declared outside functions with `var`).

So what happens exactly:

```
a := foo()
```

Here, `foo` allocates variable `x`, and returns a function that holds on to this new variable.

```
a() // returns 1
a() // returns 2
```

The `x` variable created by `foo` is incremented, and its new value is returned each time.

Now that you know this, you should be able to work out what the output here will be:

```
a, b := foo(), foo() // creates 2 functions, 2 variables called x
_ = a()
_ = a()
fmt.Printf("a call returned %d\nb call returned %d\n", a(), b())
```

The output should be *"a call returned 3 b call returned 1"*